# Best way to code a big one-click toggle button to replace a single checkbox and submit button form?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, togglebutton

I've got a page that has a simple one checkbox form with a submit button for users to mark that item as "want to play."

Given the simplicity, I'd like to replace it with a single DIV and graphic of a toggle button or switch or something, so that users can click it to mark, but not have to bother with the silly single checkbox and submit button, which is rather ugly.

The short and quick solution I can think of is for the div to be a link like

`markme.php?id=XYZ&user=123`

that pops the flag into the database for that user and then redirects back to the page they were viewing.

Would that be reasonable? Is there a better way?

/me is an enthusiastic beginner

Comment: Why not make it an AJAX request instead, so the user never has to actually leave the page they were on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it a `<button>` which has an `onclick` event bound to it that performs an AJAX request to submit the request to some page handler that will update the database or similar, and on successful completion changes its CSS style to make it look pressed.

Use jQuery for the [event binding](http://api.jquery.com/click/), [AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), and [CSS class changing](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), and [this style](http://doctype.com/make-button-appear-pressed) should work to make the button look depressed.

```
<button type="button" id="btnPlay">Play</button>
```

Then:

```
 $("#btnPlay").click(function(){

    var button = $(this) ;

    if (!button.hasClass('pressed')) {
        //button is unpressed
        $.post("ajax.php", { userId: "5512", action: "play" },
            function(data){
               button.addClass('pressed');
               button.html("Playing!") ;
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        //button is pressed, toggle it back
        $.post("ajax.php", { userId: "5512", action: "stopPlaying" },
            function(data){
               button.removeClass('pressed');
               button.html("Play") ;
            }
        );
    }


});
```

Comment: Impressive, and a lot of new ground to cover for me. Thank you for the challenge!